# Run a batch file in a new window from batch?

Tags: batch-file, window, command

I know it seems this has been asked before, but I need a batch to open another batch in a new window. I've tried:

```
start abc.bat

cmd abc.bat

run abc.bat
```

and others. They've all opened in the same window or just opened Command Prompt in new window, ignoring my batch. Is there a batch command to open a batch file in a new window?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's a little bit strange that `start abc.bat` doesn't work but I assume this is because you are running this in the middle of another batch. You probably need `call`:

```
22:22:38.85 c:\help call
Calls one batch program from another.

CALL [drive:][path]filename [batch-parameters]
```

Giving you `start call abc.bat` or `call start abc.bat` depending on what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 48):

Is this what your after?

```
start "New Window" cmd /c test.cmd
```

Answer (score 7):

To simply do it is just

```
start cmd /c "exampleexample.bat"
```

This could also work with spaces;

```
start cmd /c "example example.bat"
```

And directories.

```
start cmd /c "C:\NAME\Example\Hi there\example example.bat"
```

I created my universal batch with this and this works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

`start abc.bat` works for me. What is the problem in your case? You could also try `start cmd /c abc.bat`.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that works:

```
call "C:\FILEPATH HERE\abc"
```

Demo:

```
@echo off

call "C:\Users\USERNAME HERE\Desktop\abc"
```

This should work <3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly, I know of no such method (I encounter the same thing). However, try killing the old window when you start the batch

abc.bat:

```
abd.bat
stop
```

abd.bat:

```
@echo off
@echo It works!
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are going to run it in a different command prompt, type start C:\abc.bat or whatever the directory of abc.bat is, or if you want to open it in the same command prompt, type call "C:\abc.bat" again, wherever the directory is. It should work

Either:
call "C:\abc.bat"
or
start C:\abc.bat