# How to make batch file open new CMD with commands in it?

Tags: matrix, batch-file, cmd

How can I make a batch file open another CMD window with this in it?

```
Title Matrix
color a
mode 1000
:start
Echo %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random%
Goto start
```

Comment: please specify your operating system

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Notepad
2. Paste your Above code
3. save the file as filename.bat or filename.cmd
4. double click it to execute

Answer (score 1):

Use `start` command:

```
start myFile.bat
```

Also, check [Run a batch file in a new window from batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074849/run-a-batch-file-in-a-new-window-from-batch)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want. it's simple. learn some commands, but here is your code:

```
echo.@echo off>matrix.bat
echo.Title Matrix>>matrix.bat
echo.color a>>matrix.bat
echo.mode 1000>>matrix.bat
echo.:start>>matrix.bat
echo."echo. %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random%    %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random% %Random%">>matrix.bat
echo.goto start>>matrix.bat
start matrix.bat
goto :eof
```