# Open dotnet applications in separate window using bat file

Tags: batch-file, dotnet-cli

I have *bat* file which contains

```
dotnet ...\something.dll
dotnet ...\stuff.dll arguments
dotnet ...\others.dll
```

What I want is when run bat file, open three separate windows with different application.

In first window, executes something.dll, other window stuff.dll, etc

How to achieve in bat file command?

Comment: If you want them to open in different windows try `start cmd /c "" "Line"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `start` command:

```bat
start dotnet ...\something.dll
start dotnet ...\stuff.dll arguments
start dotnet ...\others.dll
```

If you want to wait until each process finished add a `/wait` flag:

```bat
start /wait dotnet ...\something.dll
start /wait dotnet ...\stuff.dll arguments
start /wait dotnet ...\others.dll
```

Or to be sure a new window will be opened start a new cmd window with:

```bat
start cmd /c dotnet ...\something.dll
start cmd /c dotnet ...\stuff.dll arguments
start cmd /c dotnet ...\others.dll
```

`/c` option in `cmd` command carries out the command specified by string and then terminates.

Replace it with `/k` (Carries out the command specified by string and remains).

An interesting reference: [Run a batch file in a new window from batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074849/run-a-batch-file-in-a-new-window-from-batch)